# Handheld Systems Archives CD-ROM

Tags: handheld, magazine

Does anybody know if this is available anywhere?

The domain seems to be gone.

Comment: It's a pity this is closed, as it sounds interesting. Was there any similar publication for the 2000's? Maybe something that covered the Sharp Zaurus series?

Comment: It is probably closed because the latest edits has removed all information in the question.

Answer (score 2):

If the site and company are no longer in existence then it may have to come down to using one of the many online auction sites ( eBay / SellMyRetro ) etc amongst others to see if said CD Rom is up for sale there.

Assuming it is not in archive.orgs CD software collection that is and you want or need original media.

Copyright status I could not comment either way on as the material in question I am not familiar with.

Comment: Could you please delete this non-answer so that I can delete the question.